# Como extrair String de uma string maior separada por "/"

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma string e desejo extrair uma substring veja no meu código:

```
 String link = "lojas/RJ/Macaé/Loja Modelo/pedidos_ativos/03-03-2018-8773";
    String uf = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/",0),link.lastIndexOf("/",1));
    String cidade =link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("/",1),link.lastIndexOf("/",2));
    Log.e("eutag","UF dada: "+uf);
    Log.e("eutag","cidade dada: "+cidade);
```

Preciso retornar em uf tudo que está entre o primeiro "/" até o segundo "/"
e em cidade do segundo "/" até o terceiro "/" porém este meu código apresenta erro:

Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=57; regionStart=-1; regionLength=0
                                                                                   at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
                                                                                   at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)
                                                                                   at com.dgsistemas.criappstore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não seria mais fácil utilizar o método [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)?

```
String link = "lojas/RJ/Macaé/Loja Modelo/pedidos_ativos/03-03-2018-8773";
String[] partes = link.split("/");
System.out.println(partes[0]); // lojas
System.out.println(partes[1]); // RH
System.out.println(partes[2]); // Macaé
System.out.println(partes[3]); // Loja Modelo
System.out.println(partes[4]); // pedidos_ativos
System.out.println(partes[5]); // 03-03-2018-8773
```

> Funcionando em [repl](https://repl.it/repls/FinishedAffectionatePerimeter)

Comment: muito bom obrigado mesmo